# Calling a subview

Tags: ios

```
#import "sideTableViewController.h"

@interface sideTableViewController ()
{

    NSArray *colours;
}
@end

@implementation sideTableViewController
@synthesize colorNames;
@synthesize sideTableView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.sideTableView.delegate= self;
    self.sideTableView.dataSource=self;
    colorNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Archie",@"Sethi",@"Rajan" ,@"Deepak" ,nil];

}
- (NSInteger)sideTableView:(UITableView *)sideTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    
{
    return [colorNames count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)sideTableView:(UITableView *)sideTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [sideTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[colorNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // NSLog(@"the indexpath is %@",indexPath);
    return cell;

  }

- (void)sideTableView:(UITableView *)sideTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [sideTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
[sideTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and this is the header file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface sideTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *colorNames;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *sideTableView;
-(IBAction)showMessage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *colorNames;

@end
```

I'm trying to get an image as a background to an existing tableview.
i'm getting an exception regarding:   [sideTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7593640

please help i'm new in IOS programming!

Comment: Have you set your Datasource and delegate for Tableview in Xib/Storyboard?

Comment: Replace delegate and datasource methods  with standard UITableView delegates and datasource methods. Read this https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i have already done this can u please provide me code

Comment: You can see in above link. You can get more than enough material on above link. Just go thorugh once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may this code help you simply add the below code to just above

```
- (NSInteger)sideTableView:(UITableView *)sideTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

add this code

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your support..
can you mail me the code...  my mail id is- architgrover@hotmail.com